# How to determine federation name and AD FS issuer url endpoints from client?

Tags: windows, security, adfs

We are deploying a .net client application and want to authorize the windows user on the client with their AD FS.

How can one extract the following information client side in order to auth with AD FS:

- Federation name: MicrosoftOnline
- AD FS issuer URLs:

  - https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf
  - https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf
  - https://login.microsoftonline.com/GetUserRealm.srf

**Is their a way to get this information from the registry or the domain controller or similar?**

When the user is visiting for example company.sharepoint.com they are authorized by the ADFS. Can we observer the auth process and get the information from there?

Answer (score 1):

Customer's ADFS environments have the Federation Metadata URL that is published both on the intranet (by ADFS) or on the extranet (by the WAP server).

The URL structure should be
https://adfs-service-hostname/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml

Thanks
//Sam (@MrADFS)

Comment: That's quite helpful, any idea how one can determine the adfs-service-hostname on the windows client?